# Getting the error "Number of packages exceeds maximum" from FedEX API

Tags: perl, fedex

I am getting "FedEx Ship Error: (8522) Number of packages exceeds maximum" error. I am trying to send a multiple-package shipment request to fedEX, but it is getting failed in first package request only.

For sending multiple shipment request to FedEX, we have to send separate request for each package, the master tracking information will be returned in reply from the first package requested. That master tracking information is then inserted into the requests for each additional package requested for that multiple-package shipment.

The example below is first package request.

Below is the XML request Body I am sending to FedEX API "https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/xml"

The code is just preparing the data structure, converting it into XML and hitting the fedEX API with XML request.

```
my $http_request = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $config->{'URL'});
$http_request->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$http_request->content(Encode::encode_utf8($xml_request_body));

my $http_response;
eval {
    $http_response = $ua->request($http_request);
};
return errorShipResponse($p) if (!defined $http_response || !$http_response->is_success);

my $response;
eval {
    $response = XML::Simple::XMLin(
        $http_response->content,
        ForceArray => 1,
        NSExpand => 1
    );
};
```

**$xml_request_body**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v12">
   <WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <UserCredential>
         <Key>aaaaaaaaaaa</Key>
         <Password>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Password>
      </UserCredential>
   </WebAuthenticationDetail>
   <ClientDetail>
      <AccountNumber>111111111</AccountNumber>
      <MeterNumber>111111111111</MeterNumber>
   </ClientDetail>
   <Version>
      <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
      <Major>12</Major>
      <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
      <Minor>0</Minor>
   </Version>
   <RequestedShipment>
      <ShipTimestamp>2016-09-06T06:42:41-04:00</ShipTimestamp>
      <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
      <ServiceType>SMART_POST</ServiceType>
      <PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
      <TotalWeight>
         <Units>LB</Units>
         <Value>15.00</Value>
      </TotalWeight>
      <Shipper>
         <AccountNumber>111111111111</AccountNumber>
         <Tins>
            <TinType>BUSINESS_STATE</TinType>
            <Number444444444444</Number>
         </Tins>
         <Contact>
            <CompanyName>aaaaaaaaaaaa</CompanyName>
            <PhoneNumber>11111111</PhoneNumber>
         </Contact>
         <Address>
            ADDRESS HERE
         </Address>
      </Shipper>
      <Recipient>
         <Contact>
            <PersonName>mukta jain</PersonName>
            <PhoneNumber>1234567899</PhoneNumber>
         </Contact>
         <Address>
            <StreetLines>lwehcfkwdjh</StreetLines>
            <City>NY</City>
            <StateOrProvinceCode>NY</StateOrProvinceCode>
            <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <Residential>true</Residential>
         </Address>
      </Recipient>
      <ShippingChargesPayment>
         <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
         <Payor>
            <ResponsibleParty>
               <AccountNumber>444444444</AccountNumber>
               <Tins>
                  <TinType>BUSINESS_STATE</TinType>
                  <Number>4444444444</Number>
               </Tins>
               <Contact>
                  <CompanyName>aaaaaaaaa</CompanyName>
                  <PhoneNumber>111111111</PhoneNumber>
               </Contact>
               <Address>
                  <ADDRESS HERE>
               </Address>
            </ResponsibleParty>
         </Payor>
      </ShippingChargesPayment>
      <SmartPostDetail>
         <Indicia>PARCEL_SELECT</Indicia>
         <AncillaryEndorsement>ADDRESS_CORRECTION</AncillaryEndorsement>
         <SpecialServices>USPS_DELIVERY_CONFIRMATION</SpecialServices>
         <HubId>1234</HubId>
         <CustomerManifestId>123456</CustomerManifestId>
      </SmartPostDetail>
      <LabelSpecification>
         <LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType>
         <ImageType>EPL2</ImageType>
         <LabelStockType>STOCK_4X6</LabelStockType>
      </LabelSpecification>
      <RateRequestTypes>LIST</RateRequestTypes>
      <PackageCount>3</PackageCount>
      <RequestedPackageLineItems>
         <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
         <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
         <Weight>
            <Units>LB</Units>
            <Value>5</Value>
         </Weight>
         <Dimensions>
            <Length>7</Length>
            <Width>7</Width>
            <Height>7</Height>
            <Units>IN</Units>
         </Dimensions>
         <CustomerReferences>
            <CustomerReferenceType>INVOICE_NUMBER</CustomerReferenceType>
            <Value>E2315141</Value>
         </CustomerReferences>
         <CustomerReferences>
            <CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</CustomerReferenceType>
            <Value>E2315141</Value>
         </CustomerReferences>
      </RequestedPackageLineItems>
   </RequestedShipment>
</ProcessShipmentRequest>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is not clear. All you show is a bunch of data, but no code. We don't know what you are trying to do, how that API works or how you are trying to do it. Please [edit] your question and include more information, like the code you are running, if you think that the problem is code-related. However, I think it is not. The error message is pretty clear. You should look at the FedEx developer documentation, find error 8522 and read more about it there. It seems like your shipment is too big. But that is hardly a Perl issue I'm afraid.

Comment: Your request says ```<PackageCount>3</PackageCount>```, but you only list one package.  I think that is your problem.  Package count needs to match the number of packages you are providing.

Answer (score 1):

You give us almost nothing to work with, so it's hard to be any help at all. But there's one thing that seems strange in your request body. Assuming that you're showing us a dump of a Perl data structure, it seems weird that all of your scalar values are implemented as anonymous arrays. For example, the line defining the package count is:

```
'PackageCount' => [ 3],
```

Where I'd expect to see:

```
'PackageCount' => 3,
```

It's possible that you have access to some documentation that tells you to do it this way, but it seems strange to me.

It would also explain the error message as the array reference would be interpreted as an integer which would almost certainly be far greater than any number expected by the API!

**Update:** When I wrote this answer, the question included what looked like a large Perl data structure which exhibited the weirdness that I discuss above. Now that has been changed to an XML document which seems to have the correct values. I have no idea where the original data structure came from or how it was used. And, in the absence of any feedback from the original poster, I have no idea how useful this answer is.

Comment: Hi Dave, Original was a perl datastructure which we are internally refining so that a proper XML request is generated. The final XML request that I'm sending to FEDEX API is now updated in my original question. As you can see from there <PackageCount> is 3 and with that I'm sending details of 1st package. The answer that you gave pointed out the use of array ref, which is not an issue here since I'm converting it to XML. And the same code is working fine if it is a single package request.

Comment: But that Perl data structure has a possible error in it (as I've described in my answer). Have you addressed that? Can we see how you get from the Perl data structure to the XML?

Comment: Dave, I have updated my reply. I'm new to SO, so excuse me regarding updating old comments. So, again, the final request that I'm sending is in XML and which is a correct one as you can see. I'm not sure if it is still significant how I'm converting perl data to XML, since my XML output is actually correct. I have gone through the FEDEX API documentation and it is mentioned there that in case of multiple package shipment, this is how we should make request and for further requests we should include 'MasterTrackingId' which we receive from first request. Does this clear your doubts?

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you have a question for the Fedex API support team, rather than Stack Overflow :-)